# RetroFit: Imposible subir imagen a través de POST. Valor null

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

Voy a explicar mi problema. Tengo un formulario que quiero subir una imagen. Para ello he visto que hay que utilizar el Multipart que ofrece RetroFit.

Mi **interfaz** que conecta con el apiService es esta:

```
@Multipart
@POST("usuarios/")
Call<Usuario> registrarUsuario(

        @Part("email") String email,
        @Part("location") String location,
        @Part("telegram") String telegram,
        @Part("phone") Integer phone,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo_profile
);
```

Y mi **clase** donde actua el formulario es esta:

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private MyApiService mApiService;
...
@Override

public void registerAccount() {
    Log.d("registerAccount", "Llego");
    String rEmail = email.getText().toString();
    String rLocation = location.getText().toString();
    String rTelegram = telegram.getText().toString();
    String rPhone = telephone.getText().toString();

    String image_path = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/prueba.jpg";
    File imageFile = new File(image_path);

    RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), rEmail);
    RequestBody location = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), rLocation);
    RequestBody telegram = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), rTelegram);
    RequestBody phone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), rPhone);



    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/data"), imageFile);
    MultipartBody.Part multiPartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("model_pic",imageFile.getName(), requestBody);

    mApiService.registrarUsuario(email, location, telegram,
           phone, multiPartBody).enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario> call, Response<Usuario> response) {
            Log.d("registerAccount", " " + response.code());
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("registerAccount", " " + t.getCause());

        }
    });

}
```

Error 400. Intenta subir el photo_profile como null. Y eso no lo tengo contemplado en mi backend. ¿A qué es debido a que intente subir nulo ese campo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: El codigo que pusiste parece correcto y deberia estar enviando una imagen en el multipart, cual es el problema que tenes exactamente? pincha? no te llega la imagen?

Comment: Cuando te refieres a enviar un valor integer a que te refieres? por que alli en ningun momento lo estas enviando, El que intentas enviar es phone segun veo, si es por eso aplica un String.valueOf(phone), y si lo que intentas es enviar un integer, algo como un id adicional a eso que muestras tienes que ver en tu servicio si es un query lo que necesitas o un path para enviar el entero que necesites, no esta muy clara tu duda.

Comment: He actualizado el código, puse que el telefono sea un String para probar la subida de imagen pero no funciona. Parece que sube pero el campo photo_profile no lo sube.